# Access files posted through AJAX using $_FILES variable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file-upload, superglobals

Trying to learn how to use the new AJAX file uploading, instead of using iframes or the good old PHP only file uploading. I understand how XHR requests work and have been using jQuery's `$.post` for a long time. But I can't get this one.

**The reason:** when I post data (the file I want to upload) I can only access it through a `$_POST` global, not the required `$_FILES` global. Here's some of my code real quick:

```
<input type="file" id="file"/>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Upload" />
$("#file").on("change",function () {
  var file = this.files[0];
}
$("#submit").click(function () {
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file',file);

  $.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>ajax/upload.php', // point to server-side PHP script 
    dataType: 'text',  // what to expect back from the PHP script, if anything
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: formData,                         
    type: 'post',
    success: function(php_script_response){
      alert(php_script_response); // display response from the PHP script, if any
    }
  });
});
```

In the PHP script, when I `var_dump $_POST`, I'm getting the file, but when I `var_dump $_FILES` there's nothing there. I've found these resources but they don't seem to work for me:

- [AJAX File Upload with PHP, HTML5 File API and jQuery](http://www.sanwebe.com/2012/06/ajax-file-upload-with-php-and-jquery)
- [jQuery AJAX file upload PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23980733/jquery-ajax-file-upload-php)
- [jQuery AJAX file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload)

Comment: I have edited the title to describe your exact problem. Using a very specific title helps get more attention to the question. I have improved formatting of the code block, listed the resources (it wasn't very clear with the `/` in between) and also capitalized abbreviations.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the `$_FILES` array populated, content type should be `multipart/form-data`

Try instead of:

```
contentType: false,
```

Put:

```
contentType: "multipart/form-data",
```

Comment: Yay! That makes sense! How do I do that?

Comment: <form action="yoururl.php"
method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: @taxicala Ok now it says "Missing boundary in multipart/form-data POST data", I guess I have no idea what that means

Comment: @taxicala I still can't get it working. I looked up my error and I can't find a solution.